# In Microsoft javascript, is it possible to get the message property of the Error object in English?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, windows-xp

I have a script which I execute with `cscript.exe`in Microsoft Windows XP:

```
try {
   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   fso.GetFile("no_such_file");
} catch ( e ) {
   WScript.Echo(e.message+" "+e.number);
}
```

The textual output depends on the language of Windows XP.
For example on an English Windows XP I get

File not found -2146828235

While on an Italian Windows XP I get

Impossibile trovare il file -2146828235

Is it possible to get the English message disregarding the operating system language?

Comment: why would you need that? the user would presumably want to see the message in their own language, and for use within your program you should be looking at the exception type, not the error message string.

Comment: @Spudley It is a requirement: I need to write an error log file and it must be in English.

Comment: Another reason to want the error message (or at least some unique identifier) to be consistent is so that you can run different code in the `catch` block based on the error received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't get an English language error message (which in a way is nice if a little delusional, it shows that the standard does not consider that English is a "special" or universal language that is preferred over other natural languages) but you can get other information that might provide sufficient detail for your logging.  Namely, there is a [number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc53e755%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a [name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96s4ewf9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. Since your aim it to log errors, maybe you could log the error number and name and decide whether or not to also log the localized error message.